# How jquery validation is working?

Tags: jquery, html

*Hello frndz..I had used the below jquery validation in my form .. it's working properly but i have a dout that how it is giving proper "EMAIL" format..i have not used any regex and not defined it's pattern on my HTML page..how it is working....?????? and if i want to change it how come i do that..????*
**HTML page..index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<title>Table</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,700">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css"> 
<script charset="utf-8" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="webapp.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

   <div id="page_container">

  <h1>Details of Employees</h1>

  <button type="button" class="button" id="add_company">Add Employees</button>

  <table class="datatable" id="table_companies">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>Mobile No</th>
        <th>Website</th>
        <th>Functions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>

<div class="lightbox_bg"></div>

<div class="lightbox_container">
  <div class="lightbox_close"></div>
  <div class="lightbox_content">

    <h2>Add Employees</h2>
    <form class="form add" id="form_company" data-id="" novalidate>

      <div class="input_container">
        <label for="Name">Name: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="field_container">
          <input type="text" class="text" name="Name" id="Name" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$" value="" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input_container">
        <label for="Lastname">Lastname: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="field_container">
          <input type="text" class="text" name="Lastname" id="Lastname" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$" value="" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input_container">
        <label for="Email">Email: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="field_container">
          <input type="text" class="text" name="Email" id="Email"  value="" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input_container">
        <label for="Username">Username: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="field_container">
          <input type="text"  class="text" name="Username" id="Username" value="" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input_container">
        <label for="Password">Password: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="field_container">
          <input type="password" class="text" name="Password" id="Password" value="" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" placeholder="eg. X8df90EO" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input_container">
        <label for="Mobile">Mobile: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="field_container">
          <input type="text"  class="text" name="Mobile" id="Mobile"  maxlength="10" pattern="[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" placeholder="Only 10 digit Mobile no"required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input_container">
        <label for="Website">Website: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="field_container">
          <input type="text" class="text" name="Website" id="Website" value="" placeholder="https://www.domain.com" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="button_container">
        <button type="submit">Add Employees</button>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="message_container">
  <div id="message" class="success">
    <p>This is a success message.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="loading_container">
  <div id="loading_container2">
    <div id="loading_container3">
      <div id="loading_container4">
        Loading, please wait...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

**webapp.js**

```
    // On page load: form validation

   jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
   success: 'valid',
   rules: {

  Email: {
    required: true,
    email:true
  }

},
errorPlacement: function(error, element){
  error.insertBefore(element);
},
highlight: function(element){
  $(element).parent('.field_container').removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
},
unhighlight: function(element){
  $(element).parent('.field_container').addClass('valid').removeClass('error');
   }
   });
```

Comment: It's working because you specified `email:true` in the default validation settings. That uses a regular expression to compare the value

Comment: And how  format of email is getting match...without regex..

Comment: @Monty it is handled by plugin (js) itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this answer gives you more clarity.. :)

I am posting an answer as i am not able to add a comment.. :)

The email validation in your code is working as you have used Email Method of Jquery.

Please find following description of Email Method.

Email Method(Which has been used in your code) :-

Description: Makes the element require a valid email

This is the built-in Validation method for email in jquery.

It will return true if the value is a valid email address. And works with text inputs.

In case you need a custom email pattern use the $.validator.methods property.

jQuery.validator.methods:-

Description: Object holding all validation methods known to the validator. This can be accessed to override individual methods, while keeping the default messages.

Example:

Sets a custom email pattern for the built-in email validation rule.

```
 $.validator.methods.email = function( value, element ) {
      return this.optional( element ) || /[a-z]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+/.test( value );
    }
```

For more information, please visit - https://jqueryvalidation.org/email-method.